# Threebox Tooltip in 3D models

Tags: three.js, 3d, mapbox, threebox

I´ve been trying to enable tooltips on some imported 3D models, but it isnt working.

I already enabled tooltips in threbox, and I enabled tooltips in the options for the 3d element, as shown below.

```
tb = new Threebox(
    map,
        mbxContext,
    {
        realSunlight: true,
        enableSelectingFeatures: true, //change this to false to disable fill-extrusion features selection
        enableTooltips: true // change this to false to disable default tooltips on fill-extrusion and 3D models 
    }
);
```

```
var proptions = {
    obj: './models/er.glb',
    type: 'gltf',
    scale: 10,
    units: 'meters',
    rotation: { x: 90, y: 0, z: 0 }, //default rotation
    anchor: 'center',
    adjustment: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0.4 },
    enableToltips: true
}
```

When i load the object i did the following:

```
tb.loadObj(proptions, function (model) {
    model.setCoords(place);
    model.addTooltip("A radar in the middle of nowhere", true);
    model.setRotation({ x: 0, y: 0, z: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) })
    tb.add(model);
});
```

Although the object appears in the render, when I put the mouse above or i click it nothing shows the tooltip.

What am I missing ?

**EDIT:**

Following @jscastro response i changed the import in the top of my html page to `<link href="./threebox-plugin/examples/css/threebox.css" rel="stylesheet" />` (the path is the correct to where the file is)

I also removed the enableTooltip: true in proptions.

Despite that it still does not work, Below i will leave the code as it is:

```
var origin = [-8.4, 41.20, 1];
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: origin,
    zoom: 11,
    pitch: 30,
    antialias: true
});

//Things related to dateTime ommited

window.tb = new Threebox(
    map,
    map.getCanvas().getContext('webgl'),
    {
        realSunlight: true,
        enableSelectingFeatures: true, //change this to false to disable fill-extrusion features selection
        enableTooltips: true // change this to false to disable default tooltips on fill-extrusion and 3D models 
    }
);

map.on('style.load', async function () {
    await importarLinhas();
    // stats
    // stats = new Stats();
    // map.getContainer().appendChild(stats.dom);
    animate();

            
    map.addLayer({
        id: 'custom_layer',
        type: 'custom',
        renderingMode: '3d',
        onAdd: function (map, mbxContext) {

            var eroptions = {
                obj: './models/stationBus.fbx',
                type: 'fbx',
                scale: 0.01,
                units: 'meters',
                rotation: { x: 90, y: 20, z: 0 }, //default rotation
                anchor: 'center',
                adjustment: { x: -0.1, y: -0.1, z: 0.4 }
            }

            var poptions = {
                obj: './models/Busstop.fbx',
                type: 'fbx',
                scale: 0.03,
                units: 'meters',
                rotation: { x: 90, y: 20, z: 0 }, //default rotation
                anchor: 'center',
                adjustment: { x: -0.1, y: -0.1, z: 0.1 }
            }

            var proptions = {
                obj: './models/er.glb',
                type: 'gltf',
                scale: 2.7,
                units: 'meters',
                rotation: { x: 90, y: 0, z: 0 }, //default rotation
                anchor: 'center',
                adjustment: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0.4 }
            }

                allNos.forEach((element) => { //For each one of a list that i fill first
                    //center of where the objects are
                    var place = [element.lng, element.lat, 0];

                    //cylinder as "base" for each one of the 3d Models 
                    **//in here i cant do the Tooltip for the object**
                    const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.6, 0.6, 0.15, 32);
                    const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x5B5B5B });
                    const cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

                    var baseOptions = {
                        obj: cylinder,
                        anchor: 'center',
                        adjustment: { x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.4 }
                    }

                    let base = tb.Object3D(baseOptions);
                    base.setCoords(place);
                    base.setRotation({ x: 90, y: 0, z: 0 })
                    //The text is just for the test
                    base.addTooltip("A radar in the middle of nowhere", true);
                    // base.castShadow = true;
                    window.tb.add(base);
                    
                    //next i check what type of element it is 
                    //it can only be one at the same time, so i use different models for each type
                    if (element.tipo === "p") {
                        window.tb.loadObj(poptions, function (model) {
                            model.setCoords(place);
                            model.addTooltip("A radar in the middle of nowhere", true);
                            model.setRotation({ x: 0, y: 0, z: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) })
                            // model.castShadow = true;
                            window.tb.add(model);
                        });
                    }
                    if (element.tipo === "er") {
                        window.tb.loadObj(eroptions, function (model) {
                            model.setCoords(place);
                            model.addTooltip("A radar in the middle of nowhere", true);
                            model.setRotation({ x: 0, y: 0, z: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) })
                            // model.castShadow = true;
                            window.tb.add(model);
                        });
                    }
                    if (element.tipo === "pr") {
                        window.tb.loadObj(proptions, function (model) {
                            model.setCoords(place);
                            model.addTooltip("A radar in the middle of nowhere", true);
                            model.setRotation({ x: 0, y: 0, z: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) })
                            // model.castShadow = true;
                            window.tb.add(model);
                        });
                    }

                });

        },

        render: function (gl, matrix) {
            window.tb.setSunlight(date, origin.center);
            window.tb.update();
        }

    })
    map.addLayer(createCompositeLayer());

    map.on('SelectedFeatureChange', onSelectedFeatureChange);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
I downloaded the page you shared in the chat, and I found many different issues and mistakes in your code.

**1.** You're using the wrong property to enable the selection of 3D objects, you use `enableSelectingFeatures: true, //change this to false to disable fill-extrusion features selection`, that is for Mapbox fill-extrusions features as said in the comment, but not for 3D models and objects, you have to use `enableSelectingObjects: true`. Only adding this, your problem with the tooltips on mouse over will be solved.

```js
tb = new Threebox(
    map,
        mbxContext,
    {
        realSunlight: true,
        enableSelectingObjects: true, //enable 3D models over/selection
        enableTooltips: true // enable default tooltips on fill-extrusion and 3D models 
    }
);
```

But I have found other issues...
**2.** Your models `scale` initialization is too small, so you are hiding them below the big shapes you have created. The scale of your bus stop is `scale: 0.01` and you define a place which is on the ground `var place = [element.lng, element.lat, 0];`, so it's hidden inside this `CylinderGeometry`
[image]
If you use `scale: 1` you will see how your bus stops raises from the cylinder.
[image]

**3.** Same with the bus, you initialize them with `scale: 1,` which make them be hidden below the tubes and cylinders you have created. If you initialize them with `scale: 10,` and you elevate them 5 meters from the floor `let truck = model.setCoords([lngB, latB, 4]);` then you will see them raising.
[image]

**4.** Your models have a wrong initialization params mixing `anchor` and `adjustment`. `anchor: center` will center the pivotal center of your object properly, but then you apply negative values to x and y (which means decenter the object), and a z value that elevates the pivotal center `adjustment: { x: -0.1, y: -0.1, z: 0.4 }`. If you want your model on altitude use the 3rd coord in `setCoords`.

**5.** Your Cylinders and Tubes for the bus stops and bus lines are huge, and also they have the wrong init params, as you set them below the ground level `-0.4` units `adjustment: { x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.4 }` (something supported by Mapbox but very bad resolved and producing weird effects. My recommendation would be to make them almost flat and at the ground level with no `adjustment` param. `const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.6, 0.6, 0.01, 32);`.

Summarizing, check all of these changes and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I changed the import in the top of my html and i removed the enableToltips: true in var proptions, but it still does not show the tooltip. I will update my post for more code

Comment: Yes please, add the full code of the page and a link to the model you are loading, and I'll review it. It must work

Comment: This is the link of one of the models [link] https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/kyoto-cityscene-bus-stop-5eb07fc3b28f474dbf15b1bbac814c82

I use some other models retrived from windows 3D Vizualization, but i dont have a link to it.

Comment: your model from windows 10 3D is the yellow one or the red one??

Comment: The bus is not used in the part of the code i posted, it is ommited as i dont want to put a tooltip in that model, but just for testing i tried but it did not work

Comment: Got it, I updated my answer, the problem with the shadow is in the bus stop model. With the tooltips I didn't find any issue loading the 3 of them, the tooltip is shown properly on mouseover and selected, so please share your full code, because you should have something wrong in the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227101/discussion-between-jscastro-and-tiagofonseca1109).